# How can I make my users go to next step automatically after 30 seconds?

Tags: php

I have a code that makes my users go to next page after click on ( click here to continue ) button
I want to make my user going to next step automatically after 30 seconds

```
    <div class="col-md-<?= $col_num ?>">
        <?= $this->Flash->render() ?>

        <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['id' => '']); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden('action', ['value' => 'continue']); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->hidden('page', ['value' => $page + 1]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Click here to continue'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary',]); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Javascript, or maybe a meta tag with refresh command to a different URL. PHP can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a click on the button after 30 seconds using JavaScript. First, add a unique identifier to your button

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Click here to continue'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'auto_click']); ?>
```

And then add the following JS close to the closing body tag of your HTML content

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('auto_click').click();
    }, 30000);
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fruh89d4/)